# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException while implementing JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, nullpointerexception, jframe

My task is to create a java program implementing GUI about a BMI Converter that takes in height and weight. Currently it is no finished but i am receiving the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
   at BMIGUI.<init>(BMIGUI.java:60)
   at BMITest.main(BMITest.java:7)
```

while debugging it with a friend of mine, he suggested that my error is that i havent initialized my variable "frame" in BMIGUI code. But upon second look, it seems correct according to me..

Please help. Thanks

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class BMIGUI extends JFrame
{
   private final int WIDTH = 275;
   private final int HEIGHT = 100;

   DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat ("0.00");

   private JFrame frame;
   private JPanel panel;
   private JLabel heightLabel, weightLabel, BMILabel, resultLabel;
   private JTextField height, weight;
   private JButton calculate;


   public BMIGUI()
   {
      super("BMI Converter");

      heightLabel = new JLabel ("Your height in meters:");
      weightLabel = new JLabel ("Your weight in kilograms: ");

      //create a "this is your BMI" label
      BMILabel = new JLabel ("Your BMI is ") ;
      //create a result label to hold the BMI value
      resultLabel = new JLabel ("") ;

      //create a JTextField to hold the person's height in inches
      height = new JTextField (5);
      //create a JTextField to hold the person's weight in pounds
      weight = new JTextField (5) ;

      //create a button to press to calculate BMI
      calculate = new JButton ("calculate BMI");
      //create a BMIListener and make it listen for the button to be pressed
      calculate.addActionListener ( new BMIListener () ) ;

      //set up the JPanel to go on the JFrame 
      panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setPreferredSize (new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
      panel.setBackground (Color.yellow);

      //add the height label and height textfield to the panel
      panel.add (heightLabel) ;
      panel.add (height) ;
      //add the weight label and weight textfield to the panel
      panel.add (weightLabel) ;
      panel.add (weight) ;
      //add the button to the panel
      panel.add (calculate) ;
      //add the BMI label to the panel
      panel.add (BMILabel) ;
      //add the label that holds the result to the panel
      panel.add (resultLabel) ;

      //add the panel to the frame 
     frame.getContentPane().add (panel);
   }


   public void display()
   {
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }


   private class BMIListener implements ActionListener
   {

      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
      {
         String heightText, weightText;
         double heightVal, weightVal, bmi;

     //get the text from the height and weight textfields
     heightText = height.getText();
     weightText = weight.getText();

     //Use Integer.parseInt to convert the text to integer values
     heightVal = Double.parseDouble (heightText) ;
     weightVal = Double.parseDouble (weightText) ;

     //Calculate the bmi = 703 * weight in pounds / (height in inches)^2
     bmi = weightVal / (heightVal*heightVal) ;

     //Put result in result label.  Use Double.toString to convert double to string.
     resultLabel.setText( fmt.format(bmi) ) ;

      }
   }
}
```

the main class

```
 import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class BMITest extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        BMIGUI frame = new BMIGUI();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(350,100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't initialized the `frame` declared in your `BMIGUI` class context although you are referencing it. Such as:

```
frame.getContentPane().add (panel);
```

And other places. As `BMIGUI` itself your frame window, In fact you don't need to declare another frame instance in `BIMGUI` context at all, replace `frame` reference with `this` which will refer to the current referencing instance.

This is always considered as good practice:

1. always Override `getPreferredSize(Dimension)` instead of `setPreferredSize()`
2. calling `pack()` instead of using `setSize(Dimension)` : The `pack()` method sizes the frame so that all its contents are at or above their preferred sizes.

please, [follow java's usual coding convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html). The first name of a class start with capital later, but all of the letter should not be, such as `BIMGUI` should be `BimGui`. We use all capital letter to represent constant field: `public static final int DATAMARKER`

Comment: I understand the tip you are telling be about naming convention. Thank you for the tip. I will definitly remember it. As for the frame, is the line "private JFrame frame;" in the instance variable outside the BMIGUI constructor incorrect or misused?

Comment: Thank you. After re-reading your statement, i have understood. It is now working. Thanks alot!

Comment: make sure to check the [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) to know how this site works and welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: Thank you. Ill be sure to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
add (panel);
```

instead of

```
frame.getContentPane().add (panel);
```

why declare a JFrame in a class that extends a JFrame?

Comment: Thank you! You have been a great help!